# jquery if condition issue

Tags: jquery

I have a function to push array, but i am getting the issue, because of allways my conditions are checking together. apart from this, if i use curly brase i am getting created the array no. of times. even i unable to explain properly here, pls look my code :

```
$.map(pObj,function(values,i){
    if(typeof pieArray[values.GeoID] == 'undefined')
        pieArray[values.GeoID] = []; //it should create only one time

    pieArray[values.GeoID].push(values.ResponsePercentage); // when it matches it should not go down to check next if. else it can go.

    if(!values.GeoID && typeof pieArray[0] == 'undefined')
        pieArray[0] = []; //it should create only one time

    pieArray[0].push(values.ResponsePercentage); //now the top if get response, till it is checking and throwing error. top if not match, then it need to work.
});
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Please don't take it as an insult, but i am not a native english speaker and between your poorly formatted question and the grammar i'm having a hard time trying to understand what you're saying. Could you explain it again, or provide more code?

Comment: i am sorry. i got some workaround and the issue fixed. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did like this. it works fine.

```
var pieArray = [];
var allIndia = false; //using as a key.

$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (pObj) {
        $.map(pObj,function(values,i){
            if(typeof pieArray[values.GeoID] == 'undefined') pieArray[values.GeoID] = [],allIndia = false;//making false
            pieArray[values.GeoID].push(values.ResponsePercentage);

            if(!values.GeoID && typeof pieArray[0] == 'undefined') pieArray[0] = [], allIndia = true;//making true, so it will not go down the first condition matches.
            if(allIndia) {pieArray[0].push(values.ResponsePercentage)};
        })
        pieArray = $.grep(pieArray,function(n){
            return(n);
        });
        console.log(pieArray);
        makePieChart();
        },
        error: function (err) {
        //console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply need to use control blocks (`{}`).

```
$.map(pObj,function(values,i) {
        if(typeof pieArray[values.GeoID] == 'undefined') {
           //it should create only one time
           pieArray[values.GeoID] = [];
           // when it matches it should not go down to check next if. else it can go.
           pieArray[values.GeoID].push(values.ResponsePercentage);
        }
        if(!values.GeoID && typeof pieArray[0] == 'undefined') {
           //it should create only one time
           pieArray[0] = [];
           //now the top if get response, till it is checking and throwing error. top if not match, then it need to work.
           pieArray[0].push(values.ResponsePercentage);
       }
    });
```

Comment: that's what i say, when i do like this, 'pieArray[values.GeoID] = [];
' is creating no.of times according to the values.